# XML or RSS file with json or jsonp?

Tags: jquery, xml, json, rss, jsonp

I was wondering if this can be done. A little explanation:
I have a customer review system. Every new review can be seen by Google as new content. Therefore I have to dynamically load the XML or RSS feed into my html page. I have no access to the server to use PHP, everything have to be done with jquery, AJAX and/or JSON(P).

If I make a simple request like so (one of the url's) I get a syntax error.:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var url ="https://www.abc.com/widgetfeed.php?company=1234"; // this is a RSS feed
    var url ="https://www.abc.com/xml/recent_company_reviews.xml?connectorcode=1234&company_id=1234 // this is a XML feed

    $.getJSON(url+"&callback=?", function(data){

    });

 });
```

IS this even possible? I've read about YQL and so on but that isn't a solution for me! Does anyone know how to do this, with what or can tell me if this is even possible let me know. Thanks

Comment: XML and json are different formats - you can't get XML using a `getjson` method.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ might be want you want

Comment: You use 2 same-named `var url`. Attention.

Comment: with no server access...YQL seems like simplest approach if API doesn't serve jsonp

Comment: @ChrisW: thanks I'll try that one... Yes I do know what JSON is and what it does. This was just a question IF there may be a solution for this since more people have the same question on this forum and the rest of the internet!

Answer (score 1):

> IS this even possible?

No. Data expressed as XML is not data expressed as JavaScript (which JSON-P is) so can't be loaded by pretending it is a script.

> I've read about YQL and so on but that isn't a solution for me!

If you aren't willing to use a server side XML to JSON-P converter (even a third party one) then you are stuck (assuming the URLs are on a different origin and thus prevent you using plain old XHR to start with).